# Django Ajax Form Works but Throws 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've researched this to death, but have not found exactly what I need to get the last part of my form completed.

I have a simple 2-field form in my footer for newsletter signup.  I am utilizing an `inclusion_tag` since I need to include the form on every page.

The form works; with a couple of hitches, for arguments sake, it works, I hit submit and the email is sent to me.  The problem is that I am getting a `500(internal server error)` in console on the ajax url. I am assuming that its not really supposed to redirect to the url, but rather just process the form. Below is my code; I hope someone can easily point out my issues.  Thanks.

**Inclusion Tag**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('includes/cta_form.html', takes_context=True)
def footer_newsletter_signup(context):
    title = 'Newsletter Signup'
    form = CTASignupForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': title,
    }
    return context
```

**Ajax**

```
$('#sendSignupForm').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var mForm = $('#signupForm').serialize();
  console.log(mForm);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'pages:cta_signup' %}',
    data: mForm,
    success: function (data) {
      $("input").val('')
    },
    error: function (data) {
      $("input").addClass('error')
    }
  })
})
```

**cta_form.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'pages:cta_signup' %}" method="POST" id="signupForm">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.name }}
  {{ form.email }}
  <button class="btn btn-black no-margin-bottom btn-small" type="submit" id="sendSignupForm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**View**

```
def cta_signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CTASignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = 'This is a response from Soledad Footer Signup Form'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            recipient_list = [from_email, 'charles@netfinity.net']
            ctx = {
                'subject': subject,
                'name': name,
                'email': email
            }

            message = get_template('email_forms/cta_signup_email.html').render(Context(ctx))
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email=from_email, to=recipient_list)
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send()

            messages.success(request, "Thank you, we received your message")

        if form.errors:
            json_data = json.dumps(form.errors)
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

**Screenshot of Console Error**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view must always return a response. You don't, if the form is valid; that's a server error.

Return `HttpResponse()` at the end of the is_valid block.